# SELECT all from v_catalog.columns not showing ALL columns

Tags: sql, toad, vertica, toad-data-point

I'm running the following statement because I'm looking for a particular column:

```
SELECT * FROM v_catalog.columns
```

The result of this query only shows me columns for five schemas.

On the other hand, the dropdown in `Toad`'s Object Explorer will display over 30 table schemas. I would think that all these tables would be displayed in the query above. I have read access to one of the tables that's not being displayed in the `select` above, so it's not permission issues.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What type of table is it(flex, temp or regular)? What is your session characteristic(read commited, serializable)?Do you know about  [`search_path`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/SET/SETSEARCH_PATH.htm)? `select * from v_internal.vs_columns;` --- also do not see your table?

Comment: This looks like two questions mashed together. Could you expand on the first question as requested and remove the second, seemingly unrelated, one?

Comment: You're right. They seem like two unrelated questions, but they are related. I will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `VIEW_COLUMNS`. Also, the column names would all need to be upper case. It worked.